# how can i destroy a prefab i instantiated?? (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a level loading system for my game without switching scenes. i can load (intantiate) a level but i cant unload it (destroy it). here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelLoadingSys : MonoBehaviour
{

   public void loadLevelT()
   {
       GameObject LvlT = Instantiate(LevelTutorial);
       load();
   }

   //unload levels
   public void unloadLevelT()
   {
       Destroy(LvlT);
   }

   //levels
   public GameObject LevelTutorial;
```

please help me if you have the time.

Comment: Your problem is quite unclear. Note: unloadLevel method can not access LvlT variable as it is defined in loadLevelT method

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `GameObject LvlT = Instantiate(LevelTutorial);`, the prefab you are instantiating is stored in a local variable (`LvlT`).

This variable is droped at the end of its scope: the method `loadLevelT()` but the instantiated gameobject still exists in the scene.

The variable should also not be available in the `unloadLevelT()` method. *Aren’t your editor and/or Unity displaying error about it ?*

If you want this to work, you should declare `LvlT` as a class field or property instead of a local variable so it could be accessible by all your class methods.

This could be a working version of your class:

```cs
public class LevelLoadingSys : MonoBehaviour
{

   public void loadLevelT()
   {
       LvlT = Instantiate(LevelTutorial);
       load();
   }

   //unload levels
   public void unloadLevelT()
   {
       Destroy(LvlT);
   }

   //levels
   public GameObject LevelTutorial;
   private GameObject LvlT;
}
```

Note that I may have miss something. Try to post your whole class the next time so we do have the full context.

Comment: thank you for helping me! i am very new to game development and programming in general and i dont understand much.  unfortunately the code you sent didnt work. but you made me understand the problem and i was able to fix it. once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

working code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelLoadingSys : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject LvlT;

    public void loadLevelT()
    {
        LvlT = Instantiate(LevelTutorial);
        load();
    }
    public void unloadLevelT()
    {
        Destroy(LvlT);
    }

    //levels
    public GameObject LevelTutorial;
}
```